# Creating a list and assigning value

Tags: java, java-8

Do we have any other new feature to achieve the below code in better way (jdk 8).

```
final List<Student> studentList= new ArrayList();
final Student std= new Student();
std.setName(value);
studentList.add(std);
```

Comment: Use a constructor with `name` parameter instead of `setName()`? but "better" is depends on your specific case, we can't really answer that.

Comment: @Guy thank you for your suggestion, I had replaced the setter with constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use raw types (look at the diamond operator at the end of the declaration) and favor constructor over setter when you can :

```
final List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
studentList.add(new Student(value));
```

If the list is designed to be immutable, with Java 9 it would be just :

```
final List<Student> studentList =  List.of(new Student(value)) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Student> list = Stream.of(new Student("name"))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The name of the student would be passed in constructor instead of a setter.

Or via `Arrays` **(exists since JDK 1.5)**

```
List<Student> list = Arrays.asList(new Student("name"));
```

`Arrays.asList()` method can take as many objects (student) as you want to. Check its [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)).

Comment: Thank you, This is what I'm looking

Comment: Great, it helped!

Comment: `Arrays.asList` doesn’t stop working in Java 8 or newer. But here `Collections.singletonList(new Student("name"));` might be even better.

Comment: Of course! I meant that it exists way before JDK 8. Since he asked a Java 8 syntax